# Azure API Management Self-hosted Gateway for Openshift

Tags: openshift, apim

Does MS offer Azure API Management Self-hosted Gateway version specifically certified to deploy on Openshift.
I have noticed that many vendors provide product version that is enterprise tested and certified to deploy on Openshift PaaS.

Thanks
Sudhi